# How to convert from data generator to tensorflow queue for multi gpu training. cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py sample

Tags: tensorflow, queue

I have a data generator for training a CNN and works fine. Now I want to speed up training on 2 GPUs (on 1 pc)  by following cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py. (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues)

Questions:

1) How to convert data generator to queue? Data item: (image file dir, output). Whole dataset: list of data items. Batch dataset: partial whole dataset. How to put it into a tensor like following:

```
  batch_queue = tf.contrib.slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue(
        [images, labels], capacity=2 * FLAGS.num_gpus)
```

2) What is content of the queue?

1.a) The queue take whole dataset or single batch dataset?

1.b) It seems to me in cifar10 sample, the queue is 1 batch. But, how it cycle through all dataset?

1.c) If queue take whole dataset, what is the data in each thread of gpu? In such case, I am not sure I understand how concurrent GPU training is possible, as each dataset used to calculate loss and gradient depends on same model state. But, next loss+gradient of next dataset calucation is possible only after last one is done to modify the model weight.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might work is something like:

- Build lists

  ```
  image_list = [("file%d" % i) for i in range(100)]
  label_list = read_label_list_from_disk(path)
  ```
- convert image_list and label_list to tensors
- Producer

  ```
  image_filename_queue, label_queue = 
         tf.slice_input_producer([image_tensor, label_tensor], ..)
  ```
- Reader

  ```
  reader =tf.WholeFileReader()
  key, value = reader.read(image_filename_queue)
  images = tf.image.decode_png(value)`
  ```
- Batching

  ```
  image_batch, label_batch =
         tf.train.batch([images,labels_queue],batch_size=batch_size)
  ```
- Prefetching

  ```
  batch_queue = tf.contrib.slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue(
                    [image_batch, label_batch], capacity=2*gpus)
  ```

Hopefully, this explains the concept of the queue in Tensorflow as well.